# Trimming user input/text in API

Tags: api, validation, text, user-input, trim

What are the best practices for handling user input? Need to trim the text entered by users?
If I will trim all user input, what issues can appear?
Or is better to trim when sending response to user?

Comment: You need to ensure user input is secure. But if you should "trim" it depends entirely on the context, the data, the application, the source, the destination, etc etc. What do *you* mean by "trim", removing whitespace at the start end end, or something else? What programming language are you even using?

Comment: We are building a marketplace application. Java.